# Are substituents placed alphabetically in the name of a cycloalkane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry, cyclohexane

I named this molecule **1,5-diethyl-2-methyl-4-propylcyclohexane**. Is this correct? Or should we somehow use the size of the substituents?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, simple prefixes (like methyl, ethyl, and propyl) are arranged alphabetically disregarding any multiplicative prefixes. Any multiplicative prefixes are inserted later and do not alter the alphabetical order.

The corresponding actual wording of the nomenclature rules (taken from *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*) reads as follows.

> **P-14.5** ALPHANUMERICAL ORDER
>
> Alphanumerical order has been commonly called ‘alphabetical order’. As these ordering principles do involve ordering both letters and numbers, in a strict sense, it is best called ‘alphanumerical order’ in order to convey the message that both letters and numbers are involved
>
> Alphanumerical order is used to establish the order of citation of detachable substituent prefixes (not the detachable saturation prefixes, hydro and dehydro), and the numbering of a chain, ring, or ring system when a choice is possible.
>
> (…)
>
> **P-14.5.1** Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

Therefore, the name for the compound that is given in the question is **(1*S*,2*S*,4*S*,5*S*)-1,5-diethyl-2-methyl-4-propylcyclohexane.**